# How to find the nth term and limit of sequence in the form of $a_{n+1}=b\ln{(a_n^2+c)}+d$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

My problem is $a_{n+1}=\frac{2011}{3}\ln{(a_n^2+2011^2)}-2011^2$ with given $a_1=a$. I have no idea at all about what I should do. PLEASE HELP

Comment: You want to find what? A closed-form solution, a sum, a limit?

Comment: @healynr the nth term and a limit